# How to loop through UIButtons with only certain border colors?

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, uibutton

I am trying to loop through certain `UIButton`s with only certain border colors. For example, I am looking to loop through `UIButton`s that are only currently showing the border color light gray. I understand how to loop through all buttons in a view like this:

```
      for (_buttonField  in self.view.subviews)
```

But I cannot figure out how to only select `UIButton`s that are only currently bordered with the light gray color(or any specific color for that matter). I then want to delete these UIButtons with this specified UIColor border. I know this is done with removefromsuperview, but I am not sure what to call prior to that. I am actually trying to do this when I press a 'Delete' button in a UIAlertController.

Comment: what property of the button is coloured grey? is it the button.backgroundColor?

Comment: no, like this:

_buttonField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;

Comment: Can you guarantee that all subviews are buttons when executing that loop?

Comment: yes I can, I am only creating buttons within this subview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compare the colors using `isEqual` since you do not want to compare pointers but the color values.

```
for (UIButton *button in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([[UIColor colorWithCGColor:button.layer.borderColor] isEqual:[UIColor lightGrayColor]]) {
        [button removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
for (UIButton *buttonField in self.view.subviews {
 if (buttonField.layer.borderColor == [UIColor lightGreyColor].CGColor)
  [buttonField removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't base anything on the colour. Technically you can compare colours, but it's the wrong thing to do. It would mean interrogating the view to decide on a logical outcome when really you should be interrogating your model. Think MVC or MVVM.

So, your buttons represent some part of your model, and each has a colour which represents some attribute in the model. When the delete action is fired it should be linked to a value that you can compare this attribute to to decide what to delete. Then you update the model.

Once the model is updated you update the UI. Often the easiest way to do that is to collate your button references in a dictionary where the key is the value from the model and the value is an array of all of the buttons which correspond to that value. So, all of the buttons in an array have the same colour, and each array has a different colour from each other.